# WebView video full screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I am playing a video inside webview and I want the video player in webview to enter full screen when the page load. You can see the code below:

`controller.evaluateJavascript(source: "document.exitFullscreen()");`  works fine but `controller.evaluateJavascript(source: "document.requestFullscreen()");`  is not working fine. Actually I dont want user to press full screen button on video player to enter full screen. Also the video player shows many nudity ads but in full screen it donot show any ad.

```
InAppWebView(
            key: webViewKey,
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.url)),
            initialOptions: options,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
              webViewController = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
                this.url = url.toString();
              });
            },
            onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              controller.evaluateJavascript(
                  source: "document.requestFullscreen()");
            },
            onEnterFullscreen: (controller) {
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
              ]);
            },
            onExitFullscreen: (controller) {
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
              ]);
            },
            shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
            },
          )
```